# URL auto rewriting

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

In my blog I use URL rewriting. The true url for a post is domain.com/article.php?id=3 and every time I post a new article, I have to edit the .htaccess to automatically redirect to domain.com/article/name_of_the_post.

Is there a way to automatically make this rewriting with the name of the article saved in my sql database or somewhere in the post ?

Thanks

**EDIT 1 :**
I started by a php script which modified the .htaccess every time I post an article but I know its not a good solution on the long term

**EDIT 2 :**
I added this to my .htacess :

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article-([0-9]+)-(.*)$ ./article.php?id=$1 [L]`

and it makes the page `domain.com/article.php?id=3` accessible by an url like `domain.com/article-3-anyStringChain`

For more information see [this link from WordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)

Comment: search for 'slug' and '.htaccess RewriteRule regex'

Comment: What research have you atleast conducted? Use a url rewriting framework with php and a database?

Comment: Are you using a framework or CMS like `Wordpress` or `Laravel`? What is the code processing your URLs in `PHP`?

Comment: I'd also recommend to _not_ develop on the production machine. And to switch off error_reporting in production. Now you have a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/u585243969/public_html/blog/article.php on line 35`. In production.

Comment: @Jeff I corrected the error but how can I do differently ?

Comment: Wordpress has a [whole page dedicated to this question](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess), have you had a look? Even if you are not using Wordpress, the syntax applies everywhere.

Comment: @DanFromGermany No but it is very interesting, i add this to my question edit

Comment: Oh I just noticed this question is old,.. are you still trying to solve the problem :-)

Comment: Aha no but I had the same problem today and I search and found my old question so I added my solution to help others if i can^^

Answer (score 0):

without more information about what framework you use etc., I only have suggestions:

1) place the name in your query string too, so that you can rewrite it based on it directly. it will not be visible in the browser anyway due to rewriting and QSA. 
in other words: the name should be part of your URL

2) make every call of a URL like article.php?id=3 perform a redirect itself in order to go to suggestion 1) after fetching the name out of your database

Comment: I don't understand anything^^
Yes, I want to rewrite with the name of the article is it what you are saying ?

Comment: yes - but you of course need to get the name of the article in your URL some way. the best way (suggestion 1) would be to put it in your query string, e.g. `article.php?id=3&name=foobar_article_name` 

second would be that you call article.php?id=3 and this script redirects you then to article.php?id=3&name=foobar_article_name` after fetching the name from your database

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want not the user being able to see `article.php?id=3` so I'll try to edit the links in the pages with PHP...

Comment: ah ok, I see...if such URLs should not be visible at all, you have to either use hashes (which would cause ugly URLs like `article.php?ajfdsöoajwrf934afrfj934` that can not/hardly be guessed by the user or ... edit the linky by hand if its possible to have at least 2 articles having the same name. if not, you don't need the id and could directly call `article.php?name=name_of_the_post` and rewrite this then to your desired structure `/article/name_of_the_post`